# Will my phonegap app be rejected if it opens a server website

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, appstore-approval, inappbrowser

I am wondering if my app will get approved or not if it is only a website which is on the server.

I have designed a cordova app which is just redirecting to a website. After redirecting to the website, the user will access whatever there is in the website only.

So is there a chance that my app get rejected by the apple?

This point is from Apple's guideline:

***Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected***

And then again this point

***Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript***

Answer (score 0):

If you are planing to upload this It will be rejected if its just a sample website. Apple App Review Panel will just reject this application as you have already read apple guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reviewers are human, not machines, *it could happen* that they could accept your app by chance.

However, the normal (and usual) thing is that they reject your app, since it goes against the Apple's guideline.